# Is a lambda expression possible here?

Tags: c#, lambda, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm working with  ASP.Net Core Identity Framework and  i need to collect all roles to which my user doesn't belong.
So, obviously i can do it like that:

```
SSUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
var Roles = roleManager.Roles;
List<string> notUserRoles = new List<string>();

foreach (var role in Roles)
{
    if (!await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
    {
        notUserRoles.Add(role.Name);
    }                     
}
```

And it works. But just in order to get used with lambda expressions, could you tell me, is that can be made somehow with lambda expression? I've tried to do it myself for some time, the problem is that the User property of IdentityRole  object is not actually a IdentityUser (SSUser in my case).
May be there is obvious way and i can't see it?

Comment: Show your effort; do not use uppercase for the first letter of local variables.

Comment: Well, thank you, Kalten.  Code looks strange for me, and doesn't work for now,  i'll try to figure out why. But  looks like you answered my question.

Comment: I  removed my efforts from listing, when decided to use foreach. But thanks for hint, i'll save them next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by splitting into 3 operations :

```
// Select all tasks 
var tasks = roles.Select(role => 
    new { 
        Task = userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name),
        Role = role
    }).ToList();

// Wait for completion
await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(t => t.Task));

// Filter the result and add it to notUserRoles
notUserRoles.AddRange(tasks
    .Where (t => !t.Task.Result)
    .Select(t =>  t.Role.Name));
```